# kubectl logs command does not appear to respect --limit-bytes option

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When i issue

> kubectl logs MY_POD_NAME  --limit-bytes=1

command, the --limit-bytes option is ignored and i get all the pod's logs.
My kubernetes version is 1.15.3 
Trying to understand why that would be. When i issue the same command in GKE  setup, the --limit-bytes option works as expected. I wonder what might be different in my setup to prevent this option from working correctly. (This is on CentOS).

Update: i tracked down the issue to Docker's --log-driver option.
If the Docker --log-driver is set to 'json-file', then kubectl logs command works fine with --limit-bytes option. However, if the Docker -log-driver is set to 'journald', then kubectl logs command ignores the --limit-bytes option. Seems like a kubectl bug to me.

Comment: Hi J.Doe, if you found an answer it would be best not to edit the question but to actually add the answer to the thread and accept it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

After executing this command you shoud have seen following error:

```
error: expected 'logs [-f] [-p] (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER]'.
POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command
See 'kubectl logs -h' for help and examples.
```

Execute:

```
$ kubectl logs your_pod_name  -c container_name --limit-bytes=1 -n namespace_name
```

If you set **--limit-bytes** flag you must know that 
**--limit-bytes=0**: Maximum bytes of logs to return.

Defaults to no limit.=0: Maximum bytes of logs to return. Defaults to no limit.

Documentation of [kubectl-logs](https://github.com/fabric8io/kansible/blob/master/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs.md).

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: i meant that --limit-bytes option has no effect in my installation. i give the pod name and namespace correctly. all the pod's logs are returned, regardless of the value of --limit-bytes. when i try the same test in GKE, --limit-bytes option works correctly. just wondering what in my setup can cause it not to work.

Comment: Maybe it's something wrong with your setup. Do you have properly setup memory and kubectl on your cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it should work fine -

Please try this, if you have one container in application -

```
kubectl -n namespace logs pod_name --limit-bytes=1
```

If you have multiple containers then please mention like -

```
kubectl -n namespace logs pod_name -c container_name --limit-bytes=1
```